# Code re-design to reduce redundancy

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I am refactoring my static library to reduce code redundancy.

I have come across a certain situation which is depicted in the below image.
[image]

**In this case, is going with the `Utility` class the best way out, or is there some better design pattern?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks like a good one. It's simple.

There are other patterns, but given only the information you provided, that's exactly what I would do.

One other thing to consider would be to make class A and Class B both inherit from the same super class and then place the logic in the super class.

Or better yet, make your classes POCO model objects only with no logic, and apply the logic to the superclass using a category.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I try and abstract out any common code into a `Utility` or `Helper` class. It's neat, bug fixes will apply to both and you know that both are using exactly the same method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Either extract common functionality to one superclass, or keep the superclasses as they are and reflect the common functionality in a protocol.

Deciding which solution depends on the nature of the problem, that the reflected by classes.

You can't create the utility class as you draw in your diagram because in objective C you cannot inherit from more than one superclass.

Comment: The Utlity Class is not being inherited from the two child classes. Rather it a solution that I had, but was not that convinced with it.

Comment: The problem is you do not use arrows properly (in UML compliant way). 
The arrow between Class A and Child of Class A should be reversed to reflect inheritance properly. But since you used it as you did, I respected it. But then it means in your diagram the utility class inherits from two superclasses which is impossible in objective-C.